# Why is socket.recv() sometimes blocking and sometimes not?

Tags: python, sockets, server, client

I'm trying to make a client-server application in which:

- the client sends a message (name of a function) to the server
- the server receives the message, calls the corresponding function and returns the results to the client.

I'm able to do this only if the message from the client is one; if I want to call two or more functions, and therefore send two or more messages, I get some problems because I need to add a loop inside the server.

In particular, what is not clear to me is the socket function recv(). Usually, to receive data I write something like this (without setblocking()) and I never had any problems:

```
while True:
    data = sock.recv(BUFFER)
    results += data.decode()
if not data:
    break
```

But if I add a `while True:` to the server (in order to wait for the other functions), then the client never exits from sock.rev(). Why? I expect that function to be always blocking or always non-blocking based on how it was set sock.setblocking().

I already tried with settimeout() and it worked, but performances are really important so I would like to avoid every possible delay.
Anyway, the main question is why recv() is behaving differently; then if you had any suggestions to solve my task it would be really appreciated.

Here's a simple simulation of the real application.

Client:

```
import socket

BUFFER = 1024
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_address= ('localhost', 14000)

sock.connect(bridge_address)

msg1 = "function 1".encode()
msg2 = "function 2".encode()

results1 = " "
results2 = " "

sock.sendall(msg1)

while True:
    data = sock.recv(BUFFER)
    results1 += data.decode()
    if not data:
        print('no more data')
        break        

sock.sendall(msg2)

while True:
    data = sock.recv(BUFFER)
    results2 += data.decode()
    if not data:
        print('no more data')
        break    

sock.close()

print('Results 1: ',results1)
print('Results 2: ',results2)
```

Server:

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_address = ('localhost', 14000)
sock.bind(server_address)

sock.listen(1)

msg = ""
for i in range(4096):
    msg += str(i) + " "

while True:
    print('waiting for a connection')
    client, client_address = sock.accept()

    try:
        while True:
            data = client.recv(128)
            if not data:
                print('no more data from')
                break            
            client.sendall(msg.encode())

    finally:
        print('connection closed.\n')
        client.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are explicitly forcing the server side socket to recieve the message from the client, even when the client is not sending anything.

```
data = client.recv(128)
if not data:
    print('no more data from')
    break
```

`if` case in the code snippet above will only execute when the client socket goes down.

One method to solve this would be to first send the size of the message and then call `recv` accordingly for the specified number of bytes.